# Parsing Error while uploading CSV files to AWS Neptune

Tags: amazon-web-services, csv, parsing, amazon-neptune

I want to solve Parsing Error occurring in uploading CSV files to AWS Neptune.

The problem may be occurred by column name and its type, but I do not know what types are right to write in the header.

I transformed types of all the data as string before uploading CSVs.

Problem does not occur:"~id","pv_time:String","order_num:String","staff_num:String","~label"

Ploblem occurs:"order_num","order_from:String","order_to:String","station_name:String","~label"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ~id and ~label headers are required.

Comment: Thanks, I have been able to insert the data using columns you told me.

Comment: Although I could insert the data, however, all the data I inserted was recognized as  "Vertex", not "Edge". How can I insert the data as "Edge"?

Comment: Edge definitions require a different header, i.e. `~id,~from,~to`, where `~from` and `~to` are existing vertex IDs.